# How to upload attachments in CQ using OSLC queries

Tags: clearquest, oslc

Can anyone guide me in uploading the attachment to the Clearquest tool using OSLC queries.

I am new to OSLC. so , it would be great help, if anyone provides the steps to perform for uploading an attachment.

Comment: See https://jazz.net/forum/questions/45682/accessing-clearquest-programatically/45686

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload an attachment , i used the below URL

URL : https://CQURL/oslc/repo/repo_name/db/db_name/record/Record_Type-record_identifier/field/AttachedDocuments/attachment?rcm.action=modify"

It does not allow PUT method, use POST Method and pass multipart Input, to upload an attachment.

Status will be 201, if attachment is uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

From [IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.oslc_cmrest_api.doc/topics/c_cq_oslc_rest_api_ovw.htm) (emphasis mine):

> You can use the ClearQuest OSLC 2.0 CM REST API to programmatically perform all Rational ClearQuest 8.0 functions **except adding an attachment** to a record.

Comment: Hi, i could add the attachments to a record programattically.  I used multi part input to upload the attachment.